# Failed to start a cluster manually in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-computing, performance-testing

I have just started using Spark Apache. I tested it in my local computer (Windows 10, Intel Core i5, 8 GB RAM) and everything worked correctly. When I tried to start a cluster manually I got a error as in the below attached image:
    [image]

Info from log (C:\Spark\logs\spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-XXXXXX.out:

> Spark Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin\java -cp C:\Spark/conf\;
>   C:\Spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.0-hadoop2.6.0.jar;C:\Spark\lib\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar;
>   C:\Spark\lib\datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar;C:\Spark\lib\datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar -Xms1g -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip 
>   XXXXXX --port 7077 --webui-port 8080

I use these sources to resolve this issue but no success:
    [Spark Standalone Mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#installing-spark-standalone-to-a-cluster)
    [How to Setup Local Standalone Spark Node](https://blogs.perficient.com/multi-shoring/blog/2015/05/07/setup-local-standalone-spark-node/)
    [Setup a Apache Spark cluster in your single standalone machine](http://blog.knoldus.com/2015/04/14/setup-a-apache-spark-cluster-in-your-single-standalone-machine/)

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: Can you provide the logs?

Comment: You should provide more details about error messages. You should be more specific in your question too. You could start with a full copy paste of logs. Until now it's like you are saying my app is not working and I have no idea why. I cannot help you otherwise.

Comment: Do you mean logs from 'C:\Spark\logs\' ? I pasted everything what I have there in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're slightly mixed up. When running Spark on Windows machine - it would make sense to either use remote master, or to run it locally. In both cases - use `bin\spark-shell.cmd` (or another `bin/*.cmd`). You should only execute commands which end with `.cmd` on Windows machine. When you run `start-master.sh` what you saying is - *I want to use this machine as a resource manager of a spark cluster, so other spark clients can connect to it and execute queries*. This is probably NOT what you want. When you're doing `local[*]`, you're already using all the local resources, there's no point to start "master". If you need more resources - start a remote cluster (for instance EMR) and then connect to it with `bin\spark-shell.cmd --master AMAZON.IP:7077`

Comment: Thank @avloss for your feedback. EMR is fee option. Do you have any other alternative without any extra cost for testing purpose? I still wonder if I can create a standalone cluster (one master and 4 slaves on a single machine) on Windows as it is presented at this spark tutorial for linux ([link](http://mbonaci.github.io/mbo-spark/)) ?

Comment: Well you can - but you would have to use something like [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) to get it running. Then get an `Ubuntu` imange into it [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) - and follow his steps. But again - I can't see a real point of doing it, as your Spark will be working slower (possibly much slower). But if this is more of an excercise for you, then I would say `VirtualBox` is definitely the way to go, as I doubt that anyone runs production cluster on a Windows machine anyway.